# HTML: How to position elements in a header?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to build my personal record in HTML, but I have a last problem to finish it.
I would like to build my header like that : [image: IMAGE1]

Where :
TEXT SUMMARY would be the job I'm looking for
PHOTO would be my photo
NAME would be my name
PERSONNAL INFORMATIONS would be my adress, phone number...

But I haven't really find a good way to do this... When I press CTRL+ on my browser the elements go in all ways...

```css
    /* HEADER BLOCK */
    header{
        margin: 2%;
        font-size: 15pt;
        font-family: Comic Sans MS, Comic Sans, cursive;
        width : 96%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    img#profilePhoto{
        height: 236px;
        width: 236px;
        float: left;
    }

    div#description{
        float: right;
        text-align: right;
    }

    div#search{
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 25pt;
        width: 5000px;
    }

    p#name{
        padding: 8px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 20pt;
        background-color: #7E97AD;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20pt;
    }
```

```html
 <br>
 <header>
      <img id="profilePhoto" src="images/photo.jpg" alt="Photo de Profil">
      <div id="description">
        FIELD1<br>
        FIELD2<br>
        FIELD3<br>
        FIELD4<br>
        FIELD5<br>
        FIELD6<br>
        FIELD7<br>
      </div>

      <br><br>
      <div id="search">
        <a href="general/recherche.html">ACTUALLY LOOKING FOR A POST GRADUATE
        INTERNSHIP</a>
      </div>

      &nbsp;
      <p id="name">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;NAME
      </p>
    </header>
```

Can someone tell me how to do this in a good way ?

Comment: you could use [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas) with template areas for this

Answer (score 0):

just change your css

```css
   header
        {
            display: row;
            min-width: 100%;
        }
        header img
        {
            display: table-cell;
            float: left;
            width: 25%;
            height: 150px;
        }
        header .right-banner
        {
            display: table-cell;
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
            height: 150px;
        }
        #description
        {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            text-align: center;
            width: 30%;
            background: #729FCF;
            margin-top: 4px;
        }
        #search
        {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 66%;
            margin: 30px 2%;
            text-align: center;
            background: #729FCF;
        }
        
        #search a
        {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        #name
        {
            display: block;
            background: #f00;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
   <br>
    <header>
      <img id="profilePhoto" src="https://dummyimage.com/150.png/#729FCF/#000" alt="Photo de Profil">
      <div class="right-banner">
      
      <div id="description">
        FIELD1<br>
        FIELD2<br>
        FIELD3<br>
        FIELD4<br>
        FIELD5<br>
        FIELD6<br>
        FIELD7<br>
      </div>
      <div id="search">
        <a href="general/recherche.html">ACTUALLY LOOKING FOR A POST GRADUATE
        INTERNSHIP</a>
      </div>

      &nbsp;
      <p id="name">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;NAME
      </p>
      </div>
    </header>
```